# How can I set up my Pyenv-Virtualenv in this way?

Tags: python, shell, virtualenv, pyenv

I'd like to have the following [pyenv-virtualenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv-virtualenv) setup:

```
$ pyenv which python
<pyenv_root>/versions/<my-virtualenv>/bin/python3

$ pyenv which python3
<pyenv_root/>versions/3.5.1/bin/python3

$ pyenv which python2
<pyenv_root>/versions/2.7.11/bin/python2
```

That is, I'd like the "`python`" command to refer to the local virtualenv Python version, but I'd like "`python(2|3)`" to refer to the corresponding *global* Pythons. Ideally `pip` will have the same behavior as well.

Is this setup possible? Currently I have this:

```
$ pyenv which python
<pyenv_root>/versions/<my-virtualenv>/bin/python3

$ pyenv which python3
<pyenv_root/>versions/<my-virtualenv>/bin/python3

$ pyenv which python2
<pyenv_root>/versions/2.7.11/bin/python2
```

which is close but obviously not what I'm looking for. I don't remember exactly how I set things up, but I believe it went like this:

```
$ pyenv virtualenv 3.5.1 my-virtualenv
$ pyenv local my-virtualenv 3.5.1. 2.7.11
```

If it's possible to get the config I'm looking for, how would I do it?